# When importing images from resources - Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, resources

this happens when i try to import images from resources..

```
<Border Margin="10">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15"/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

but when i import it directly like `C:/image.png` it works!!

how can i solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have added image `image.png` in your current project under folder `Resources` with build action set to `Resource`.

Comment: Then there is no issue in your posted sample code in question. Check for inner exception and post that here.

Comment: nvm.. it worked as `"/Resources/image.png"` ..dunno why tho! it should be the same

Comment: If folder exists in output bin folder, use `siteoforigin` like this: `pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/image.png.` Otherwise use `application` only and its equivalent to using `/Resources/image.png`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/image.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

Remove the `Resources` directory and try.. it will work..  You have mentioned as `C:/image.png` so it might be in your root folder.. check the file path and give it as correctly..